# Parse other XML files whilst parsing tree with HXT

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt, io-monad

I am parsing XML files that describe User Interface for a game and try to learn HXT at the same time.
I can successfully parse a single XML file. But could not figure what would be the best way to open and parse other XML files whilst inside `getWindow` function.

Each XML consists of number of `Window`s. Each `Window` has `name` and `libraryName`. The latter being the name of the XML file that describes the window.
For instance, the root looks like this:

```
<!-- DOMDocument.xml -->
<elements>
    <Window libraryItemName="window_home" name="window_home">
    <!-- data here  -->
    </Window>
    <Window libraryItemName="window_battle" name="window_battle">
    <!-- data here  -->
    </Window>
</elements>
```

And then there is a separate XML file for each window. E.g. "window_home":

```
<!-- window_home.xml -->
<elements>
    <Window libraryItemName="panel_tabs" name="panel_tabs" selected="true">
    <!-- data here  -->
    </Window>
    <Window libraryItemName="home_powerup_menu" name="home_powerup_menu" selected="true">
    <!-- data here  -->
    </Window>
    <Window libraryItemName="panel_name" name="panel_name" selected="true">
    <!-- data here  -->
    </Window>
</elements>
```

I parse root `DOMDocument.xml` with this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

parseXML = readDocument [ withValidate no
                        , withRemoveWS yes  -- throw away formating WS
                        ] 

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)

data UiWindow = UiWindow {
    wndName :: String,
    wndNameLib :: String,
    wndChildren :: [UiWindow]
    } deriving (Show)

initUiWindow = UiWindow {
    wndName = "empty",
    wndNameLib = "",
    wndChildren = []
    }


getWindow = atTag "Window" >>> 
  proc x -> do
    _libraryItemName <- getAttrValue "libraryItemName" -< x
    _name <- getAttrValue "name" -< x
    -- TODO: Open _libraryItemName XML file and parse windows in it
    returnA -< initUiWindow { wndName = _name, wndNameLib = _libraryItemName}

documentName = "DOMDocument.xml"        

parseRoot = parseXML documentName
--runX (parseRoot >>> getWindow )
```

Since the `getWindow` function is not wrapped inside `IO` what would be the best way to achieve a desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HXT combinators are polymorphic, and there is a type [`IOLA`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Control-Arrow-IOListArrow.html#t:IOLA) which implements all the XML parsing-relevant typeclasses, in addition to [`ArrowIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowIO.html#t:ArrowIO) which makes it possible to do `IO` mid-arrow.

For example, if you want to do fully recursive parsing of the files, you can do something as simple as

```
parseDoc docName = runX $ parseXML fileName >>> getWindow
  where
    fileName = docName ++ ".xml"

getWindow = atTag "Window" >>> proc x -> do
    libraryItemName <- getAttrValue "libraryItemName" -< x
    name <- getAttrValue "name" -< x
    children <- arrIO parseDoc -< libraryItemName
    returnA -< initUiWindow { wndName = name, wndNameLib = libraryItemName, wndChildren = children}
```